# Another Resources$NotFoundException on setContentView

Tags: java, android, xml, resources

There are lots of Resources$NotFoundException questions on Stack Overflow and I've reviewed them and tried the various suggestions to no avail.

I had a perfectly working layout to display some graphics with some buttons underneath and I modified some of the buttons and started to get this error.   I couldn't see anything wrong with my changes but just to narrow it down I deleted **ALL** the buttons, so now I just have a LinearLayout with an ImageView and I'm **still** getting the error.  My Java:

```
    try  {
        setContentView(R.layout.graphics);
    }
    catch (Exception e)  {
        Log.d("DGraphActivity", "setContentView crash");   
    }
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
   <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/image2"
      android:layout_width="0px"
      android:layout_weight="2"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter">
    </ImageView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

The error says *android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030005*.
In the R.java file that resource is identified with the graphics . . .

```
public static final class layout {
        public static final int addcomment=0x7f030000;
        public static final int areyousure=0x7f030001;
        public static final int downarrow=0x7f030002;
        public static final int downleftarrow=0x7f030003;
        public static final int downrightarrow=0x7f030004;
        public static final int graphics=0x7f030005;
        public static final int infofromoperator=0x7f030006;
```

I deleted the gen folder and **did a clean** the project with no improvement.  I also rebooted my PC and did an explicit close of the project.  There's nothing obviously wrong with the graphics.xml file -  it exists in the same folder with all my other XML files; it's not write-protected or hidden.  Eclipse doesn't flag any errors or warnings for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did try with an always green "clean & rebuild"?

Comment: Try Project > Clean in Eclipse.

Comment: In my original posting I said I did a clean.    I'll capitalize and bold it since apparently it's not very noticeable.  @blackbelt:  what's "always green" mean?

Comment: There should be some errors in some XML file.

Comment: @Vinothbabu I don't see any, and Eclipse doesn't flag any.  Do you see any?   It's only 13 lines long and it hasn't changed since before, when I wasn't getting this error.

Comment: Try closing and re-opening your project.

Comment: I think you can try @SagarWaghmare answer, this might help

Comment: @Sagar Waghmare I did better than that, I rebooted my whole PC.  No improvement.   I'll edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: Still i think, you should give it a try.

Comment: Give what a try?   You can't reboot your PC without implicitly closing your project.   Nonetheless I tried doing an explicit close, cleaning and rebuilding the project and still get the same exception.           What _EXACTLY_ does the Resources.NotFoundException mean?   The Google documentation is vague.    Doesn't it mean it couldn't find the xml file, or it couldn't read it, or it couldn't parse it or what?

Comment: Check the import of your R file. I think it is of android.R

Comment: @Sagar Waghmare "Check it" how?   You're not supposed to have an explicit import Android.R and I don't have one, if you do have one (because Eclipse sometimes inserts one) you're supposed to delete it.    (see: http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html)     If it can't resolve "R" at build-time there would be a zillion build errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got the answer to this on the android-developers Google groups, where I also posted this question.  The insightful programmer was "Bob Smith", just to give credit credit where it's due.

My bug was that the resource it was seeking was not in the correct res folder.   My app runs in landscape mode on a tablet.   In the manifest everything is constrained to run that way (in fact in the code it's constrained to run on one particular tablet that the company ships with their product).   All the resource and layout files live in layout-land.   Bob didn't know any of this but he asked the key question: were my resource files really in the right res folder?

Comment: Okay- I've spent the last few hours trying to diagnose the same error. My layout is in the layout-land folder as well. So my question, why is this not the "right" folder (android put it there on creation)? Is this fix to move the layout into the default layout folder or is there another fix?

Comment: @IcedDante iam facing the same problem i have my layout in the layout-land but still i get the exception should i move my layout to default layout folder?

Answer (score -3):

You can do : Project > Clean and REFRESH

Comment: I don't see anything under Project called clean and REFRESH.  I'm running Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: OK, tried that, no change.   What is refresh supposed to do?   Reading the web it looks like it's supposed to catch up any changes that might have been made outside of Eclipse.   But none of these files have been edited outside of Eclipse and I'm the only person on this project, and it's not even under source control.  Was I supposed to see anything when I clicked "Refresh?", because it didn't put up any messages or status or anything in the Console.  As I said to Sagar, I think we need to find out EXACTLY what Resources.NotFoundException really means.