# What EXACTLY does Resources$NotFoundException mean?

Tags: android

I recently posted a Resources$NotFoundException bug [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652437/another-resourcesnotfoundexception-on-setcontentview) and got the usual generic suggestions about deleting the "gen" folder, doing a clean, doing a refresh, etc, etc.  There are hundreds (thousands?) of other programmers getting the same exception and getting the same suggestions all over S.O. and the web.   But I can't seem to find anyplace where anyone describes what that error really **means**.

The documentation is vague: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.NotFoundException.html

Resources$NotFoundException is a runtime error so presumably it's looking for something in the APK file.

1. How are resources built into the APK file at build-time?  We start
   with the XML file and then what...?
2. How are they referenced at runtime?
3. What is the relationship between the resource ID I see in the
   debugger and how it's identified in the APK file?
4. What (Windows) tools can I use to examine an APK file to find these
   resource myself?

Thanks in advance for the answers to any of these questions!

PS - if you think you have an answer to the original bug please post it there and **not** to this thread; this is a different question.

Comment: The error usually means that the Android team that works on the build system thought they solved the problem of figuring out build time dependencies but failed and us developers got stuck with the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Resource can be packaged in various ways from raw assets, to optimized images to packaged byte data. All zipped into one apk. `Id` of a resource is what helps finding it back. During the development, build tool (`aapt`) continually scan `res` directory for xml, images etc and generate numeric constants in `R.java`. [Read a detail about android's build process](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html).
2. At runtime the `Resources` instance decides where to look for, depending on whether which of its get method is called. The numeric `id` helps it query the resource mapping and find the correct one. Actual data loading is handled by native low-level code.
3. Debugger can show you objects and their fields. To find out what is missing read the error message `NotFoundException` traces in logcat. It lists hex value of resource id.
4. [ApkTool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) lets you deflate an `apk` file and re-construct the `res` directory.

**Update:**

**How are resources packaged:**

If you have an apk and want to see full resource table run `aapt` tool in SDK as:

```
 aapt list -v myApp.apk
```

It will show details as:

```
Archive:  ./myApp.apk
 Length   Method    Size  Ratio   Offset      Date  Time  CRC-32    Name
--------  ------  ------- -----  -------      ----  ----  ------    ----
     468  Deflate     228  51%         0  11-07-12 23:25  29fb0660  res/color/abs__primary_text_disable_only_holo_dark.xml
     468  Deflate     228  51%       332  11-07-12 23:25  bae4791a  res/color/abs__primary_text_disable_only_holo_light.xml
    2942  Stored     2942   0%    280417  10-27-12 16:52  9b5af43b  res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_mus.png
    2330  Stored     2330   0%    283418  10-27-12 16:52  21f5ba4d  res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_pic.png
    1556  Stored     1556   0%    285810  10-27-12 16:52  31c3402b  res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_vid.png
```

You will see the method (deflate,stored etc) and offset in binary data where a resource is stored, and length, which denotes how many bytes to read after offset to get that resource.

**What does `Resources.NotFoundException` prints:**

Here's the code which generates it:

```
public void getValue(int id, TypedValue outValue, boolean resolveRefs)
        throws NotFoundException {
    boolean found = mAssets.getResourceValue(id, 0, outValue, resolveRefs);
    if (found) {
        return;
    }
    throw new NotFoundException("Resource ID #0x"
                                + Integer.toHexString(id));
}
```

Thus, it prints hex value of the `Id` which `Resources` instance is requested to load.

Here's a part of `R.java`:

```
public static int absForceOverflow=0x7f010039;
```

You can see `Id` is assigned similar Hex values.

**Can I solve this error?**

The error **should not have occurred** at first place if build tools compiled you project successfully. There's not much you can do except cleaning or rebuilding the project. This represents a bug in build tools or resource loader OR data corruption in apk on device.

Comment: "To find out what is missing read the error message NotFoundException traces in logcat."   How do I find out what those messages mean?   For example "05-21 12:47:00.060: W/ResourceType(4801): Failure getting entry for 0x7f030006 (t=2 e=6) in package 0 (error -75)"   What are t and e, and what's error -75?

Comment: The error should not have occurred at first place if build tools compiled you project successfully.  BUT, we can still find this crash in our crash analyse system, only a few of our users ( maybe 1 in 10000 ) cannot find this resource, god know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How are resources built into the APK file at build-time? We start with the XML file and then what...?

<s>Whenever you use `@+id/` in your XML, or place an item in strings.xml or your drawable folder,</s> The compiler will convert all resources in the */res* folder to an integer value that is then placed into *R.java*.

> ```
> 2. How are they referenced at runtime?
> ```

The resources are referenced by integer values that are looked up in *R.java*

> 3.What is the relationship between the resource ID I see in the debugger and how it's identified in the APK file?

From my understanding the relationship is the one that is developed in *R.java* again.

> 4.What (Windows) tools can I use to examine an APK file to find these resource myself?

Not sure...

This is all that I gathered from my understanding. If there are any false statements in here then please advise me.

Comment: "Whenever you use @+id/ in your XML, or place an item in strings.xml or your drawable folder, the compiler will convert that name to an integer value that is then placed into R.java."   But R.java only exists at **build time** not at **runtime**.   And it only has resource ID's, not the actual layouts.   So how does the layout XML get represented in the APK file and how do those resource ID's relate to that layout information in the APK file?   Remember, at runtime the APK file has to contain everything so a runtime error like Resources$NotFoundException has to be reflected  in the APK file.

Comment: Well an APK is just a fancy .zip so the R.java acts as a lookup table is my assumption.

Comment: It's a reasonable assumption but I need to get past assumptions to hard facts to understand what Resource$NotFoundException really means; we need to know the details.  IS there an actual lookup table and if so what does it index?  "The resources", we might suppose but what does that **mean**?  Does Resource$NotFoundException mean that there was no entry in the hypothetical table, or what it indexed to was not a resource, or not the right kind of resource, or what?